# Datatables row row is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have my ASP.NET Core project and in one page I display a table with DataTables version 1.10.23. The data are coming from an API. The complete code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/AdminLTEWithASPNETCore/blob/feature/excel-import/AdminLTEWithASPNETCore/Areas/Tables/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml). What I want is to display 2 icon for edit and delete and when the user click on them doing something, like redirect the use to a edit/delete page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tblList = $('#list').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        "buttons": ["pageLength", "copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"],
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "serverSide": true,
        "filter": true,
        "columns": [
            @foreach (FieldUI item in Model.Fields)
            {
                @:{ "data": "@item.Data", "name": "@item.Data" },
            }
            @if(Model.IsEditAllow)
            {
                @:{ data: null, className: "dt-center editor-edit", defaultContent: '<i class="fa fa-edit"/>', orderable: false, width: "25px" },
            }
            @if(Model.IsDeleteAllow)
            {
                @:{ data: null, className: "dt-center editor-delete", defaultContent: '<i class="fa fa-trash"/>', orderable: false, width: "25px" },
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Model.ApiUrl",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
            $('#list tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                Edit(this);
            });

            $('#list tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                Delete(this);
            });
        },
        "rowId": 'Id'
    });

    // Edit record
    function Edit(el) {
        var row = $(el).closest('tr');
        var id = tblList.row(row).data().id;
        alert('Edit ' + id);
    }

    // Delete a record
    function Delete(el) {
        var row = $(el).closest('tr');
        var id = tblList.row(row).data().id;
        alert('Edit ' + id);
    }
});
```

When the user clicks on the icon the correct function is called but this error is raised

> Countries:542 Uncaught TypeError: tblList.row is not a function
> at Edit (Countries:542)
> at HTMLTableRowElement. (Countries:530)
> at HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5429)
> at HTMLTableSectionElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5233)

For the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().id()), I have the `id` with `table.row` but it doesn't work.

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
$('#myTable').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var id = table.row( this ).id();

    alert( 'Clicked row id '+id );
});
```

### Update

I added the `rowId` in the definition of the table. The issue is still there. Apparently, `.row` is not a valid function.

[image]

Comment: i dont see definition of id in your data. neither how you add data in datatable from your json.. datatables create automatically id? i doubt... you have to initialize *rowId:*

Comment: The code is in the `Model` from the controller. in `columns` the list is build from C#. The first column is `id`. How can I initialize `rowId`? The first column is the id

Comment: i give you an example, to adapt to your case,

Answer (score 0):

a sample of how initialize id: here i initialize with a datauid

```
var table = $(".sampletable").DataTable({
  dom: "",
  // Load json with list of applicants
  ajax: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/391gc",
  columns: [{
    "data": "uid"
  }, {
    "data": "location"
  }, {
    "data": "date"
  }],
  // Set rows IDs
  rowId: function(a) {
    return 'id_' + a.uid;
  },
});
```

another sample:

```
var aDataSet = [
    ['1', 'Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['2', 'Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['3', 'Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['4', 'Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['5', 'Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['6', 'Other browsers','All others','-','-','U']
];

$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaData": aDataSet,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "Engine" },
        { "sTitle": "Browser" },
        { "sTitle": "Platform" },
        { "sTitle": "Version", "sClass": "center" },
        { "sTitle": "Grade", "sClass": "center" }
    ],
    "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', aData[0]);
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

For same reasons, I can use the variable `tblList` that I use to create a `DataTables`. `tblList` doesn't have any of the functions I need. So, what I have to do is to change only the *Edit* and *Delete* functions as follow

```
// Edit record
function Edit(el) {
    var table = $('#list').DataTable();
    var id = table.row(el).data().ID;
    alert('Edit ' + id);
}

// Delete a record
function Delete(el) {
    var table = $('#list').DataTable();
    var id = table.row(el).data().ID;
    alert('Delete ' + id);
}
```

Now, if I use the developer console in the browser, I can use `row` and all the other functions provided.

You are welcome!